# ASP.NET MVC 5: UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); is not adding user to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

I am creating users using the ASP.NET identity template.

Main code for user creation is

```
await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

It returns a success.

I am able to login via the newly created user, but I am not able to see those users in database table `aspnetusers`.

I have tried registering user view google also, user gets created, able to login also, but they are not there in database table.

I have few users in my table that I had created in the beginning, but after refreshing the `.edmx`, I am not seeing them.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
I added a default connection string in web.config above the old one, now aspnet identity is using my database for all the purposes.
new connection string is :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-MVNRJK0\SQLS17;  Initial Catalog=OxfordLibrary;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that all the users are being saved in LocalDb file specified by your connection string named "Default Connection". Make sure the connection string is correct as well as the credentials inside the connection string.

In the DBContext class, maybe inside Identity models, make sure the connection string is not "DefaultConnection").Let me know if there's any further problems.  :)

Comment: I also assumed it in begging, but other things like books(my project is about books) is getting created in the database. How can i make sure that localDb is not being used when creating users

Comment: @Rajdeep  In short, for testing purpose, you can comment the "DefaultConnection" connection string from Web.config and see if it shows error when saving data to Database. And also Find "DefaultConnection" in your entire solution to see where it is being used.

Comment: The db where data is input will be the same from where it will be retrieved. Do you more than one connection string? If so, then there's a possibility that part of app is working with one and other part with second connection

Comment: @BishalTh  and Nitin : just found that my app is having another db. that is localDb, it is using it for all the actions related to user login/register/roles etc.
I have just one connection string OxfordContext(my database) there is no localDb connection string or default connection string in my app. 
How can I make my aspnet identity to look for the OxfordContext database

Comment: I changed the connection string, now aspnet identity is using my database for all the purposes.